# Printing double linkedList in java

Tags: java, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I'm stuck on how to print a double linkedlist. I have to print 'testListStrings()' and 'testListIntegers()'

```
    private static void testListIntegers() {
    MyLinkedList<Integer> testList = new MyLinkedList<Integer>();
    testList.add(new Integer(5));
    testList.add(new Integer(4));
    testList.add(new Integer(3));
    System.out.println(" We have so far inserted " + testList.size() + " elements in the list");
    testList.remove(4);
    System.out.println(" Now, there is only " + testList.size() + " elements left in the list");
    testList.add(1, new Integer(7));
    testList.add(2, new Integer(8));
    System.out.println(" About to print content of the list");
    testList.printList();
}

private static void testListStrings() {
    MyLinkedList<String> testList = new MyLinkedList<String>();
    testList.add(new String("hello"));
    testList.add(new String("this is"));
    testList.add(new String("cs3345 project 2"));
    System.out.println(" We have so far inserted " + testList.size() + " elements in the list");
    testList.remove("this is");
    System.out.println(" Now, there is only " + testList.size() + "elements left in the list");
    testList.add(1, "a modified version of");
    testList.add(2, "cs3345 project 2, call it version 2");
    System.out.println(" About to print content of the list");
    testList.printList();
}
```

I saw maybe using a toString method but I'm not sure if that would work. My code already has a method called printList() but it doesn't take on any arguments (Professor already wrote the code for us we have to fill in the code). The print method is within the linked list class.

Update--

So now here where I'm stuck,

```
public void printList() {
    MyLinkedList testList = new MyLinkedList();

    Node temp = testList.beginMarker;

    while(temp != null){

        System.out.println(temp.myData);
        temp = temp.myHead;
    }


}
```

---My code returns null

```
public class MyLinkedList<AnyType> implements Iterable<AnyType> {
    private int theSize;
    private Node<AnyType> beginMarker;
    private Node<AnyType> endMarker;



    public class Node<AnyType> {
        public Node(AnyType data, Node<AnyType> head, Node<AnyType> tail) {
            myData = data;
            myHead = head;
            myTail = tail;
        }

        public AnyType myData;
        public Node<AnyType> myHead;
        public Node<AnyType> myTail;


    }

    public MyLinkedList() {
        beginMarker = new Node(null, endMarker, null);
        endMarker = new Node(null, null, beginMarker);

        theSize = 0;

    }

    public void clear() {
        beginMarker.myHead = endMarker;
        endMarker.myTail = beginMarker;

    }

    public int size() {

        return theSize;

    }

    public boolean exist(AnyType newVal){

        beginMarker.myHead.myData = newVal;

     if(newVal !=null){

         return true;

     }



     return false;



    }

    public boolean add(AnyType newVal) {

        { add( size(), newVal); return true;}




    }

    public boolean add(int index, AnyType newVal) {



            addBefore( getNode( index, 0, size( ) ), newVal );

            return true;

        }




    public Node<AnyType> get(AnyType nodeData) {

        Node<AnyType> node = beginMarker;

        while(node != endMarker){

            //Means node.data = nodeData
            if(node.myData.equals(nodeData)){

            return node;    


            }



        }
        return null;
    }

    //Added method
    private Node<AnyType> getNode(int index, int lower, int upper){


        Node<AnyType> x;

        if (index < lower || index > upper)
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

        if (index < size() /2){
            x = beginMarker.myHead;
            for(int i = 0; i <index; i++)
                x = x.myHead;

        }

        else{
             x= endMarker;
             for(int i = size(); i > index; i--)
                 x = x.myTail;
        }
    return x;
    }
```

Comment: My guess is that the double linked list is custom class which holds the list and `printList()` is a method inside it. Am I right?

Comment: Correct, let me add that in the post.

Comment: So what is the problem? `printList()` has accesses to the list you want to print. You don't need to pass any arguments.

Comment: haha, I gotcha I feel stupid sorry!